# Read in command line arguments to determine a polynomial

Tags: c, command-line, polynomials

I am using C language to read in command arguments of an unknown size and determine the coefficients of the polynomial, its range and the degree of the polynomial.  I'm going to use the coefficients to reconstruct the polynomial and do numerical analysis on it but I am having issues just reading in the command line arguments.

For example;

./filename 1.4 2.2 3.3 4.45 5.65 12 14

where 1.4 2.2 3.3 4.45 5.65 are the coefficients of the polynomial and 12 and 14 is the range of polynomial.

I have been struggling with this for a bit now and was able to implement code which utilized fgets and then ran a for loop to count the number of spaces in the string to determine the deg of polynomial and the number of coefficients but this code utilized the terminal and I felt like that was the wrong approach.

I am sure this has something to do with pointers but I have always struggled to master this concept

I'm curious if what I need to do is run a for loop as follows

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define EPSILON 0.01

void main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i,count;
    float a,b,c;

    count =0;

    for(i=1;i<argc;i++){
    if(argc != '\0')
    count++;
    }

    deg = count - 2;

    b= argv[count];
    a= argv[count -1];

    for(i=1;i<=deg;i++){
    str[i] = argv[i];
   }

}
```

I'm pretty much dumbfounded at this point and any advice into the right direction would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but in your second for loop there is a comma where you should have a semicolon

Comment: Also, you're not giving us compilable code. It's hard to diagnose fragments with undeclared variables.

Comment: Thanks, let me fix that!

Comment: Ok, I will update the code

Comment: The first "proper" command-line argument is in `argv[1]` (`argv[0]` is reserved for the name of the program). The number of proper command-line arguments will be `argc - 1` so you can set `count = argc - 1`. The last two command-line arguments are the range of the polymonial, so the number of coefficients is `count - 2` (or `argc - 3`). The degree of the polynomial is one less than the number of coefficients.

Comment: You can use the `strtod` function to convert the strings into numbers.

Comment: Thank you @IanAbbott your first comment effectively erases the need for the for loop counting the number of spaces and would probably help in terms of run time.  Although I'm curious about my second for loop now,  if I utilized the strtod function to read in the coefficients will I still have to run the for loop and save the coefficients into an array?  Also would it be more beneficial to use the  atof() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take this step by step.

First clearly define the format of the command line. For example, we can say that there is the program name (`argv[0]`), `n` coefficients, and two numbers, with the constraint that `n > 0`. Hence we have `argc > 3` and `n = argc - 3`.

The code needs to first check the command line and extract its content to variables of the appropriate types.

At this point you are no longer working with strings. You might need to perform additional input validation.

Finally you can process the input.

```
void usage ()
{
    fprintf (stderr, "usage: ...");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// do the actual work
void run (double coeff[], int n, double range1, double range2)
{
    int deg;

    if (n > 1) {
        deg = n - 1;
    }
    else if (coeff[0] != 0) {
        deg = 0;
    }
    else {
        // the degree of the 0 polynomial is not defined
        ...
    }
    ...
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Process command line arguments

    if (argc <= 3) {
        usage ();
    }

    int n = argc - 3;

    // The coefficients are stored from right to left so that
    // coeff[i] is the coefficient of x^i
    double coeff[n];

    double range1, range2;

    // FIXME: use strtod instead of atof to detect errors
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        coeff[n - i - 1] = atof (argv[i + 1]);
    }
    range1 = atof (argv[n + 1]);
    range2 = atof (argv[n + 2]);

    // At this point you work only with coeff, n, range1 and range2

    // Additional input validation
    if (range1 >= range2) {
        ...
    }

    // do the actual work
    run (coeff, n, range1, range2);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I'm using visual studio and its giving me errors when I try using the expression double coeff[n]; .  It is telling me I cannot allocate an array of constant size, that coeff is of unknown size, and that the expression must have a constant value.

Comment: I thought about using malloc but I'm going to assume I wont be given anything larger than a polynomial of deg 6, so I'll just assign double coeff[20] to be safe. I really appreciate your help!